# Illegal assignment from account to id

Tags: apex, soql

What is the problem with below code; it shows me error like illegal assignment from Account to id

```
Account accc=[Select Id From Account where Name='Demo Account'];
List<Contact> con=new List<Contact>();

Contact con1=new Contact(
            FirstName='Demo',LastName='Contact1',AccountId=accc
);

Contact con2=new Contact(
            FirstName='Demo',LastName='Contact2',AccountId=accc
);

con.add(con1);
con.add(con2);

Database.SaveResult[] sr=database.insert(con, false);

for(Database.SaveResult var: sr);
{
    System.debug('Result- ' + var.isSuccess());
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the Id of the Account like accc.Id instead of assigning the accc object

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated code with comments for fixes. The primary fix is to ensure that you assign the ID of the Account as the `AccountId`, rather than attempting to assign the Account record itself (which is not an ID but rather a record containing an ID).

```
Account accc=[Select Id From Account where Name='Demo Account'];
List<Contact> con=new List<Contact>();

// assign the Id from accc object
Contact con1=new Contact(
    FirstName='Demo',LastName='Contact1',AccountId=accc.Id
);

// assign the Id from accc object
Contact con2=new Contact(
    FirstName='Demo',LastName='Contact2',AccountId=accc.Id
);

con.add(con1);
con.add(con2);

Database.SaveResult[] sr=database.insert(con, false);

// removed ; after the for statement
for(Database.SaveResult var: sr)
{
    System.debug('Result- ' + var.isSuccess());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jagmohan

Comment: You're welcome @ArunVignesh